# Как правильно сформировать 1 запрос MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Есть БД `table` как сделать 1 запрос чтобы вывести 2 массива по 20 записей такого формата

array1 ['name', 'likes', 'dislikes'] сортировка по `likes` на уменьшение (10,9,8...)
array2 ['name', 'time_up'] сортировка по `time_up`(unix_time) на уменьшение

Comment: а почему один запрос-то?

Comment: запросы можно объединить в один используя union, но в таком случаев речь всегда идет об одинаковом наборе полей. Вы же тут хотите выбрать разные наборы данных, в которых пересекается только одно поле. Так что одним запросом это не делается.

Comment: @teran то есть в любом случае 2 запроса придется?

Comment: В MySQL в принципе нет типа данных "массив". Вопрос в текущей формулировке не имеет смысла.

Comment: @Akina мб это сериализованное в JSON ему на выходе хочется получить :)

Comment: @teran Теоретически - возможно... но вот меня сомневает что-то...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT "like" `type`, * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `likes` DESC LIMIT 20
UNION SELECT "timeup", * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `time_up` DESC LIMIT 20
```

=== Обновлено ===

```
(SELECT "like" `type`, a.* FROM `test1` a ORDER BY `likes` DESC LIMIT 20)
UNION ALL (SELECT "timeup", b.* FROM `test1` b ORDER BY `time_up` DESC LIMIT 20)
```

Comment: Ошибку спамит `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM`

Comment: Ах ну да забыл... Шизофрения классического MySQL'а не позволяет работать без алиасов. (....поправил)   (Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdfb33 )

Comment: ага, человек юзающий звездочки в запросах, пишет нам про шизофрению mysql, ага.

Comment: О а так работает спасибо!